# Redux-saga post data from action returns patternOrChannel is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux-saga

I am using redux-saga for api async call and it is working for other requests but not for this

This code is returning error.

```
takeLatest(FileTypes.FILE_GENERATEPRINTITEM, fileSaga.generatePrintItem, api),
```

Comment: Try `console.log(FileTypes.FILE_GENERATEPRINTITEM)` ... I suspect it will print `undefined`

Comment: @MartinKadlec. Thanks it worked